# Install\build FANN in Qt !

Tags: qt4, neural-network

I tried to integrate FANN library ( Artificial neural network ) with Qt, but I got errors!
My FANN library version is (fann-2.1.0). It doesn't contain *.dll and *.lib files. It just contains header & source files. So, I thought may I need to put all files in my project folder, but I still get errors!!

Anybody have idea about install FANN in Qt properly??

Answer (score 0):

you must be build FANN 
for windows there is a project file for VS IDE
for Linux use general meteod (configure , make , make install )
after building library you can see lib files

Comment: I used some commands to build library for qt( http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/40928): (gcc -c *.c) & (ar rv libfann.a *.o) so, i got (libfann.a) and I used it as a lib. is that enough?!